# What is the convergence radius of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}5^{n^2}x^{n^2}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

What is the convergence radius of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}5^{n^2}x^{n^2}$?

I know I can use either $p=1/{\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left\lvert\sqrt{a_k}\right\rvert}$ or $p=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\right\rvert$ for a power-series$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kx^k$ but how do I extract the $a_k$ out of this? ($a_k \neq 5^{n^2}$, right?)

Comment: in fact $p=1/\lim_{k\to \infty}|\sqrt[k]{a_k}|$

Comment: Option .Look at $\sum (5x)^{n^2}$, $|5x|<1$. What happens at $|5x|=1$?

Comment: @PeterSzilas if $\lvert 5x\rvert = 1$, the series converges, otherwise not and thank you for simplifying the expression, it makes it easier.

Comment: Doesbaddel. Yes. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\neq0$, then$$\left\lvert\frac{5^{(n+1)^2}x^{(n+1)^2}}{5^{n^2}x^{n^2}}\right\rvert=5^{2n+1}\lvert x\rvert^{2n+1}=\bigl(5\lvert x\rvert\bigr)^{2n+1}.$$Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(5\lvert x\rvert\bigr)^{2n+1}=\begin{cases}\infty&\text{ if }\lvert x\rvert>\frac15\\0&\text{ if }\lvert x\rvert<\frac15,\end{cases}$$the radius of convergence is $\frac15$.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! So I don't necessarily need to pick the $a_k$, I can also compute the whole product with the same result.

Comment: Indeed. Finding an explicit expression for the $a_k$'s is not always the best option.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$a_k=\begin{cases}5^{n^2}&\text{if }k=n^2\text{ for some }n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Hence we have $a_k=5^k$ for infinitely many $k$.

> That makes $$\limsup \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}=5 $$ and so $$p=\frac15.$$

Comment: Nice and short answer, thank you!